# Pass a primary key in a Django Create View

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm working with a class-based view in which I show a form whose information is associated with a model (**called Tratamiento**), that model has a foreign key to the model called **Paciente**.

My problem is that when saving a treatment, the form shows all the available patients, being that the behavior I want is that from a form that lists all the patients, when I select one, this patient can add a treatment. That is to say, that in a new template (in this case, I am testing with a modal) the patient is fixed and that there is not a dropdown where all the patients are shown.

This is the url:

```
url(r'^tratamiento/$', views.TratamientoCreateView.as_view(), name='tratamiento'),
```

This is my **Tratamiento** model:

```
class Tratamiento(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['doctorDerivador']
    doctorDerivador = models.ForeignKey(DoctorDerivador, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    paciente = models.ForeignKey(Paciente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    diagnostico = models.CharField(max_length=50, null = True, blank = True)
    fechaInicioTratamiento = models.DateField()
    motivoConsulta = models.CharField(max_length=100, null = True, blank = True)
    fechaFinTratamiento = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    evaluacion = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

This is my view:

```
class TratamientoCreateView(BSModalCreateView):
    model = Tratamiento
    
    template_name = '../templates/tratamiento.html'
    form_class = TratamientoModelForm
    success_message = 'Success: Tratamiento dado de alta.'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

And this is what happens to me:

[image]

Please could you tell me how I can pass a primary key to the view, since the pk is in the url. I have done some tests, but without further results.

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite the dispatch method to retrieve your specific model:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404    

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.tratamiento = get_object_or_404(Tratamiento, pk=kwargs['pk'])
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

`kwargs` has a pk field which can be specified in the URL

`dispatch` is a method in most class based views and is called before loading the view. Now you can do something with the model in other methods (ie get_context_data, post, etc).